# get duplicated fields and these fields may have spaces in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this mysql table

```
id | phone  | name
1  | 123456|  aaaa
2  | 454535|  bbbb
3  |  123456| cccc
4  | 123456 | ddd
```

based on above data these records:

```
1  | 123456|  aaaa
3  |  123456| cccc
4  | 123456 | ddd
```

are duplicated but the first one is trimmed and second has space at the beginning and the third has space at the end.

I have written this query:

```
 SELECT phone, count(trim(phone)) FROM users GROUP BY trim(phone) HAVING count(trim(phone)) > 1
```

but did not return any records.

Comment: Why not just add the `TRIM` to the selected column too?

Comment: Same is working fine for me

Comment: I guesst, too: your way should work

Comment: @ToBe i added trim to selected field to make sure return trimmed value

Comment: I was talking about the phone field. That's the one you want trimmed in your result? `SELECT TRIM(phone), ...`

Comment: i do not know why have no records when execute it :(

Comment: It's working fine for me what is your problem? check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9caa4/1

Comment: Maybe the spaces are not really whitespace but sometimes line-breaks or somehting?

Comment: Glad your question was solved, next time please read on http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask especially on what the expected result would be. Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your problem with Check for line break or carriage return. No problem with white space.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE phone REGEXP "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly cleaned up version fo your query.

```
SELECT TRIM(phone), count(id) AS Counter 
FROM users 
GROUP BY TRIM(phone) 
HAVING Counter > 1
```

This query returns the following result:

```
phone  | Counter
123456 | 3
```